# Export all data when using server side processing

Tags: bootstrap-4, datatable, export-to-excel, server-side

I am using server-side processing data table and my table length is 25 and remaining comes in the pagination button click my total data is 500.
At the time I am clicked export excel, pdf, csv the current page data only download, I want total 500 data export. And I am not displaying the page length option.

Comment: With server-side processing, the DataTable typically only contains a small subset of the overall data (enough to display one page). That is the main benefit of server-side processing: If you have thousands/millions of records, the web page only needs to receive one page of that data at a time. The downside is: if you try to export the data from the DataTable to Excel/PDF/etc. you will only get that one page of data exported. If you only have 500 records, try disabling server-side processing - and then the DataTable will contain all 500 records.

Comment: thanks a lot for your help and explanation .

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.